# saving wav files in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a code in matlab where voice is recorded and saved as .wav file with name say.wav.
But the problem which i am facing is, each time i run the code the .wav file gets rewritten. But I want the voice to be recorded into a new .wav file. How can i do this in matlab?

The code is:

```
Fs    =    1E+4;
nBits    =    24;  
nChannels = 1; 
sig = audiorecorder(Fs, nBits, nChannels); 
recordblocking(sig,5); 
sigsound = getaudiodata(sig); 
t= linspace(0, size(sigsound,1), size(sigsound,1))/Fs; 
cd F:\1hp_laptop\c\my_files 
filename = 'say.wav'; 
audiowrite(filename, sigsound, Fs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nilu said, your problem is the `filename` is constant in your script/function.

One option, as stated, would be to use some kind of timestamp, e.g. instead of

```
filename = 'say.wav';
```

you can use

```
filename = ['say_', datestr(now,'FFF'), '.wav'];
```

Alternatively, and depending upon your audio file length (if it is long enough), you can ask the user for a distinctive filename, being it by encapsulating all your code into a function and asking for a string to use as parameter `filename` or by using Matlab's `input()`:

```
filename = input('give me a filename: ', 's');
```

Comment: You're welcome! If it was helpful consider upvoting and accepting

Answer (score 2):

It is getting rewritten because you have used the constant file name.You need to make your .wav file unique to ensure that it is getting newly created. You can add current time in milliseconds to the file name to make it unique .